# Test websocket app on iPhone, Python Flask-SocketIO and Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, iphone, flask, flask-socketio

My app, Python/Flask and vanilla Javascript, is running just fine on my Mac's browsers and I have previously also been able, making sure I'm on the right network, to test my app on Safari on my iPhone 6. I did this by pointing my mobile browser to the IP given by ifconfig on my Mac and correct port. However, after adding Flask-SocketIO, which should allow for Websocket support or atleast long polling, I am no longer able to test my app on my iPhone. All is still fine on Macs browsers but all I get on my iPhone is "Safari could not open the page...".

My app is served over port 5000 but Ive also tried over 80 without any success. I've cleared cache and cookies as well, of course.

Has anyone experienced something similar or have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Have you looked in the browser's js console for errors?

Comment: @Miguel, how do I check the mobile browser js console?

Comment: Can't help you with the specifics, I don't own a iOS device myself. Maybe https://jsconsole.com/ can help if you don't have direct access from the device.

Comment: @Miguel Thanks. Don't think this will work for iOS though. Do you know if there is any issues with mobile browsers limiting or rejecting long polling or websockets?

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues, but you can verify that by yourself by visiting a site that uses Socket.IO. Try one of my apps: https://flack.miguelgrinberg.com.

Comment: Works great. Thanks @Miguel Guess there is some other issue in the app I need to dig in to.

Comment: I have this problem too where socket.io doesn't work on Mobile Safari.  Did you solve it?  I don't see any errors/warnings in the js console.  To debug, go into Settings app, and under Safari->Advanced, enable the Web Inspector.  Then connect your phone to your Mac and open Safari on the Mac.  Enable the Debug menu in Safari (Mac) and you can now debug your iPhone app.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Safari needs a Content-Security-Policy meta tag.  See more at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/